# how to test for illegalaccessException?

Tags: java, junit4

**Edit: I want to write a failing test case not a positive one.**

I am writing test cases for my Java code.How do i write test cases for a method which uses reflection api. The resulting code gives me IllegalAccessException. How do i create a scenario in my JUnit test case so that i can test for the exception.

```
public double convertTo(String currency, int amount) {
    Class parameters[] = {String.class, int.class};
    try {
        Method classMethod = clazz.getMethod("convertTo", parameters);
        return ((Double) classMethod.invoke(exhangeObject, new Object[]{currency, amount})).doubleValue();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        throw new CurrencyConverterException();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new CurrencyConverterException();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getClass());
        throw new CurrencyConverterException();
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Sriram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the reflection is an implementation detail of the method under test, you don't need to cater for it specifically. To test this method, simply do:

```
@Test
public void shouldNotThrowException() throws Exception {
    testSubject.convertTo("JPY", 100);
}
```

If there is a `CurrencyConverterException` thrown, your test will fail.

Or, more explicity:

```
@Test
public void shouldNotThrowException() {
    try {
        testSubject.convertTo("JPY", 100);
    } catch(CurrencyConverterException e) {
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Note, when you catch an exception and throw a new one you should always chain the original exception in the new one. For example:

```
 } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
     throw new CurrencyConverterException(e);
 }
```

**Edit**: Are you looking for this pattern instead? How to ensure that an exception is thrown. Two variants:

```
// will pass only if the exception is thrown
@Test(expected = CurrencyConverterException.class)
public void shouldThrowException() {
    testSubject.doIt();
}
```

or

```
@Test
public void shouldThrowException() {
    try {
        testSubject.doIt();
        fail("CurrencyConverterException not thrown");
    } catch (CurrencyConverterException e) {
        // expected
        // use this variant if you want to make assertions on the exception, e.g.
        assertTrue(e.getCause() instanceof IllegalAccessException);
    }
}
```

Comment: No i want to write a failing test case. Not a positive one.

Comment: second one. shouldThrowException